# Python Как достать название переменной переданной в аргументы функции

Tags: python

```
def sample(objectName):
    # variable_name==objectName
    variable_name = [k for k, b in locals().items() if b == []][0]
    return variable_name
name=[]
print(sample(name))#output = objectName, а мне нужно чтоб name
```

Есть какие-то способы?

Comment: Так нельзя. Нужно передать имя переменной в параметрах функции самому. Это похоже на [проблему XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy/710#710) Опишите изначальную задачу

Comment: Это название не играет никакой роли за пределами функции, так что по сути ненужно, если хотите передавать именованные параметры в функцию то IDE могут предлагать подстановки или просто смотря на реализацию функции.

Comment: @RomanKonoval Задача в цикле создать несколько списков, названия  не предсказуемы поэтому хотел через функцию.

Comment: @Kers спасибо, но не совсем понял(

Comment: Добавил в ответ вариант с примерами. И как у вас в цикле могут быть не предсказуемы названия списков?  Приведите пример кода думаю что там все решается немного проще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имена переменных функции Вам могут быть нужны если вы передаете именованный параметр:

```py
def fun(name):
    print(name)

s = "Hello"
fun(s) # Как позиционный
fun(name = s) # как именованный

# относительно списка
l = ["a", "b", "c"]

for i in l:
    fun(i)
```

Как понимаю `name` это то что вы хотите узнать?
В функцию вы передаете не имя переменно а как бы ее содержимое которое в пределах функции может именоваться совсем иначе.

Comment: Очень интересно! Спасибо, пример надоумил меня на одну мысль. Тупо сделаю write, read  в отдельный файл.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sample(**kwargs):
    variable_name = [k for k, v in kwargs.items() if v == []][0]
    return variable_name


print(sample(name=[]))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]